# Regular system of parameters as generators of the maximal ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let us consider $A$ a regular local noetherian ring that contains an algebraically closed field $k$ and whose residue field is again $k$ (eg. the local ring of a nonsingular variety over $k$ at a closed point). We denote by $\mathfrak{m}$ the maximal ideal of $A$.

Let $\overline{t_1},\ldots,\overline{t_r}$ be a basis of the $k$-vector space $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$, where $r=dim(A)$. Let $t_1,\ldots,t_r \in \mathfrak{m}$ be representatives of $\overline{t_1},\ldots,\overline{t_r}$. By Nakayama's lemma, we know that the $t_i$'s form a minimal set of generator of $\mathfrak{m}$.

Does it follow that for each $i$, $t_{i+1}$ is not a unit and not zero divisor in $A/(t_1,\ldots,t_i)$ ? If so, could someone please provide me a proof of this statement or a reference for it ?

I thank you very much for your help.

NB: For context, this interrogation rises from the proof of Proposition III.10.4 in Hartshorne's book.

Comment: Proving that it is not a unit is easy.

Comment: Proving that it is not a zero divisor is trickier, and boils down to the non trivial fact that a regular local ring is integral.
If you're willing to accept that then your result follows easily by induction using the hauptidealsatz. If you're not you can find this result in matsumura, it's not too hard to prove using cohomological methods, I believe it is done in this way in Lang's algebra.

Comment: I see why proving that it is not a unit is easy.
I can also accept that such a ring is a domain, I have already seen this result once.
However, I am still not so sure about how the induction goes. The initialization ($t_i$ is not a zero divisor in $A$) is obvious. As soon as we take the quotient of $A$ by $(t_1,\ldots ,t_i)$ however, we loose the property of being a domain, being regular, and even being reduced (so that the zero divisors in the quotient are seemingly not just the union of the minimal prime ideals). Could you please tell me more about how the Hauptidealensatz should be used?

Comment: If $A$ is a local notherian ring and $t\in \mathfrak{m}$ is a non zero divisor then $\text{dim}(A/(t))=\text{dim}(A)-1$ by the haupitdealsatz, as the dimension $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m^2}$ also decreases by 1 in the quotient (you kill $t$) you get that $A/(t)$ is also regular. And thus integral.

Comment: I should add that in the second part of my sketch of proof I assume that $t$ is an element of your family $t_1,...,t_n$, but the relevant point is that $t$ is not in $\mathfrak{m}^2$ which is the case for any $t_i$ of your family : they're a basis of $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$

Comment: Naturally ! I only had the version of the Hauptidealensatz about the height of prime ideals that are minimal among those containing our fixed non-zero non-unit element in mind. I failed to notice that it implies the equality you stated about the dimension of the quotient.
I should have been more careful about believing that we would lose regularity.
Thank you very much.